# Angular JS Unit Testing(Karma Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service like this:

```
.service('sampleSvc', function($http, $q, $window, modalSvc){ ...
```

Do I have to inject `$http` `$q` `$window` `modalSvc` as dependencies while I am doing unit testing? I am always getting an error when I inject like this `Unknown Provider: modalSvcprovider<--modalSvc<--sampleSvc ..`
Am I missing something? I have given paths to the source and spec files in `karma.conf.js`

This is how I am injecting dependencies

```
beforeEach(inject(function( $http, $q, $window, modalSvc){
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to style your text. It makes it way easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
var $http, $q, $window, modalSvc;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$http_, _$q_, _$window_, _modalSvc_) {
  $http = _$http_;
  $q = _$q_;
  $window = _$window_;
  modalSvc = _modalSvc_;
});
```

Without declaring the variables outside the beforeEach, they won't be available outside of the function.